Http requests not working on Flutter IOS release mode
I am building an Flutter app that has web views, using the flutter_inappwebview package.
On android, after I added the INTERNET permission to the to the AndroidManifest.xml, it worked flawlessly.
On IOS, I added to the Info.pilst through XCode:
App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads
After that, the web views load on debug mode, but when i run
flutter run --release
it stops working.
Flutter 3.27.1 
Xcode 16.2
MacbookPro M1, macOS Sequoia 15.1.1
Iphone 11, iOs 17.7.1
